# JSONP callback doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I wrote a `Foo` constructor, that have a `load` function for upload JSONP. `script.src` has a callback, but I've got an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: bar is not defined`. How I can fix it?

```
function Foo(params) { 
    function bar(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }

    function load() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = Config.apiUrl + '&callback=bar';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', load, false);
}
```

Usage:

`var foo = new Foo(params);`

Can be a lot of in the page.

Comment: how do you call the constructor, how does the JSONP look like?

Comment: Hi! Usage `var foo = new Foo(params);`, looks like json.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your JSONP-response is correct and looks like this:

```
bar(/*some argument*/);
```

the issue: `bar` must be global accessible, but currently it isn't(it's only visible inside `Foo`)

Possible workaround:

define `bar` as a method of `Foo`, then you be able to execute it(as long as the instance `foo` is global accessible). The `callback`-parameter must be set to `foo.bar` in this case:

```
function Foo(params) {

  this.bar=function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }

  this.load=function(){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = Config.apiUrl + '&callback=foo.bar';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', this.load, false);
}

//assuming you create the instance in global scope
var foo = new Foo(params);
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer, but it's can be a more than one in the page.

Comment: provide the name of the instance(foo,bar etc.) as argument to the constructor, then you may create the callback-parameter dynamically based on the instance-name

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer:*

You should make `bar` function available globally or make it a public method of a `Foo` instance which should be available globally.

Since you have that error, you know that you need a server which returns a valid javascript code string like:

```
alert('JSONP in action'); bar('result');
```

on your `/?callback=bar` request.

So, as `JSONP` is just an odinary script load on your page, it has the same variable accessibility rules as any other .js file you load in the head section of your html and, obviously, you can't access a "private function" from a different .js file.

> But what about "saving bar function reference for later use" feature
>   (closure)?

- you may ask

It doesn't apply here, because the scope of the bar function call is created outside from the Foo constructor - the bar function is called from a "different file", so no closure here.

**Better solution:**

Assuming you need to make Cross Origin requests (`CORS`) and you can make changes in your server side apps, it's better to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` rules on the server you're trying to reach from different domain name app. This will allow you to use usual `XHR` requests and have much more information about http status codes or send custom different requests.